# Miller-Rabin primality test, begginer reading pseudo code

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

I was reading Miller-Rabin primality test Wiki and I can't understand something, it says that:

Now, let $n$ be prime with $n > 2$.  It follows that $n − 1$ is even and we can write it as $2s \cdot d$, where $s$ and $d$ are positive integers ($d$ is odd).  For each $a \in (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$, either

$$a^{d} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

or

$$a^{2^r \cdot d} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$$

I understand this as, if the result is $1$ or $n - 1$, then it is probably prime.

But in the pseudo code says:

```
...
if x = 1 then return composite
...
```

I don't get it.

Also, I get $d$ by doing this:
$$
d = \frac{n-1}{4}
$$

I work in Python, but I'm more of trying to learn all those math symbols such as $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$

When should I get **composite** and when **probably prime**?

Comment: I dont want to read other code, becouse I'm doing project Euler, which will totally spoil it if i read any code at all.
I'm willing to understand why it says $a^{d} \equiv 1\pmod{n}$ and in the pseudocode says

    if x = 1 then return composite

Comment: Well, have you read any other sources on the algorithm including the paper?

Answer (score 1):

First part of answer:

```
...
if x = 1 then return composite
...
```

This is correct, because if $x=1$ then all other squaring operations $x := x^2 \pmod{n}$  in the loop leave $x=1$ and therefore 
$$a^{2^r\cdot d} \not \equiv -1\pmod{n}$$

Second part: You get $s$ and $d$ from $n-1$ with a loop like this (the loop invariant is $n-1= 2^s d)$

```
d := n-1;   
s := 0;   
while even(d) do begin
  d := d/2;
  s := s+1;   
end;
```

Comment: Can't i write d like this:

    d := (n-1) / 4

And s will always be 2, so

    2^2 * d

I will still produce a number n-1, is this reasonable?

Comment: No is is wrong, take e.g. $n=7$ where $n-1=6$ is **not** a multiple of 4!